# Вывод принятых данных с помощью SX1278

Tags: массивы, arduino

Суть проекта заключается в том, чтобы передать некоторые данные с одной Arduino Nano на другую Arduino Nano и вывести их на OLED дисплей. На стороне передатчика находится датчик давления BMP180 и часы реального времени DS3231, на стороне приёмника находится OLED дисплей. Связь осуществляется с помощью приёмопередатчиков SX1278 E19 868MS20S, работающих по протоколу LoRa WAN. Передатчик отправляет приёмнику дату, время, температуру и давление. Дальше всё понятно, приёмник всё ловит и выводит на экран.
Собственно, к проблеме. Проблема заключается в том, что данные передаются последовательно друг за другом и принимаются точно так же последовательно. Т.е. на приёме должен быть некий массив в который будем записывать последовательно дату, время, температуру и давление, но данные в массиве со временем начинаются перемешиваться, например, в ячейке, где должна была лежать дата, залезает давление и тд. Пробовал ставить задержки на приём/передачу каждого параметра - не помогло. Может кто-нибудь решал аналогичную задачку, помогите советом.

**Скетч передатчика:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP085.h>
#include <DS3231.h>

RH_RF95 rf95;
Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;
DS3231 clock;
RTCDateTime dt;

void setup() 
{
  clock.begin();
  clock.setDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) ; 
  if (!bmp.begin()) {
  Serial.println("Could not find a valid BMP085 sensor, check wiring!");
  while (1) {}
  }

  if (!rf95.init())
    //Serial.println("init failed");
    rf95.setTxPower(20,false); //мощность передатчика 20 дБм
    rf95.setFrequency(868); //частота передатчика 868 МГц
}

void loop()
{
  dt = clock.getDateTime();
  String hh = String(dt.hour); //переводим в строки целочисленные значения
  String mm = String(dt.minute);
  String ss = String(dt.second);
  String y = String(dt.year);
  String m = String(dt.month);
  String d = String(dt.day);
  String date = d+"."+m+"."+y+"."; //дата: дд.мм.гггг
  String time1 = hh+":"+mm+":"+ss+"."; //время: чч:мм:cc

  uint8_t date1[date.length()]; //следующие две строки нашёл в интернете
  date.toCharArray(date1, date.length()); //не знаю как работает это :)
  rf95.send(date1, sizeof(date1)); //отправляем данные
  rf95.waitPacketSent(); //задержка
  delay(100);

  uint8_t time2[time1.length()];
  time1.toCharArray(time2, time1.length());
  rf95.send(time2, sizeof(time2));
  rf95.waitPacketSent();
  delay(100);

  String P = String(bmp.readTemperature());
  P = P+".";
  uint8_t P1[P.length()];
  P.toCharArray(P1, P.length());
  rf95.send(P1, sizeof(P1));
  rf95.waitPacketSent();

  String T = String(bmp.readPressure()*0.0075006);
  T = T+".";
  uint8_t T1[T.length()];
  T.toCharArray(T1, T.length());
  rf95.send(T1, sizeof(T1));
  rf95.waitPacketSent();

  Serial.println(date); //печатаем в сериал монитор дату и тд
  Serial.println(time1);
  Serial.println(T);
  Serial.println(P);

}
```

**Скетч приёмника:**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF95.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_RESET 4
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);
RH_RF95 rf95;

String data[4] = {"date1", "time", "temp", "pressure"}; //массив приёма
int i = 0;

void setup() 
{
  display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C);
  delay(500);


    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial); 
  if (!rf95.init())
    Serial.println("init failed"); 
    rf95.setFrequency(868); 
}

void loop()
{    
  if (rf95.available()) //если приёмник доступен
  {
    uint8_t buf[RH_RF95_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
    if (rf95.recv(buf, &len)) //если приняли buf длиной len
    {   
      data[i] = (char*)buf;  //в data[0] пишем дату, data[1] время и тд.
      Serial.println(data[0]); //выводим на сериал монитор
      Serial.println(data[1]);
      Serial.println(data[2]);
      Serial.println(data[3]);

      display.clearDisplay(); //очищаем OLED дисплей
      display.setTextSize(1); //размер текста 1
      display.setTextColor(WHITE); //цвет текста белый
      display.setCursor(0,0); //ставим курсор в X = 0, Y = 0
      display.print("Date: "); //выводим дату
      display.print(data[0]);

      display.setCursor(0,8); //аналогично осталное
      display.print("Time: ");
      display.print(data[1]);

      display.setCursor(0,16);
      display.print("T=");
      display.print(data[2]);

      display.setCursor(50,16);
      display.print("P=");
      display.print(data[3]);

      display.setCursor(0,24);
      display.print("RSSI: ");
      display.print(rf95.lastRssi(), DEC); //выводим мощность принятого сигнала
      display.print(" dBm"); 

      display.display();
      i++; //прибавляем счётчик
      if (i == 4) i=0; //если массив переполняется, то обнуляем счётчик
      delay(200);
    }
    else
    {

    }
  } else 
  {
      display.clearDisplay(); //если нет сигнала пишем "NO SIGNAL!"
      display.setTextSize(2);
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0,0);
      display.print("NO SIGNAL!");
      display.display(); 
  }
}
```

***Пример исходящих данных (от передатчика)***

```
18.08.2019. //дата
22:15:30. //время
746.95. //давление 
24.00. //температура
18.08.2019.
22:15:30.
746.95.
24.00.
18.08.2019.
22:15:30.
746.97.
24.00.
18.08.2019.
22:15:31.
746.98.
24.00.
```

*P.S. Точку в конце ставил из-за того, что при передаче последний символ "съедается". Не знаю как и почему, но это так.*

***Пример входящих данных***

```
23.80 //температура
22:15:35 //время
23.80 //температура

23.80
22:15:35
23.80

23.80
22:15:35
23.80

746.95
22:15:35
23.80

746.95
22:15:36
747.01

746.95
22:15:36
747.01

746.95
22:15:36
747.01

18.08.2019 //дата
22:15:36
747.01

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:37

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:37

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:37

22:15:38
23.80
22:15:37

22:15:38
747.01
22:15:38

22:15:38
747.01
22:15:38

22:15:38
747.01
22:15:38

23.80
747.01
22:15:38

23.80

23.80

23.80

23.80
22:15:39
23.80

23.80
22:15:39
23.80

23.80
22:15:39
23.80

746.95
22:15:39
23.80

746.95
22:15:40
23.80

746.95
22:15:40
747.02

746.95
22:15:40
747.02

18.08.2019
22:15:40
747.02

18.08.2019
23.80
747.02

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:41

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:41

22:15:42
23.80
22:15:41

22:15:42
23.80
22:15:41

22:15:42
23.80
22:15:42

22:15:42
23.80
22:15:42

23.80
23.80
22:15:42

23.80

22:15:42

23.80

23.80

23.80

23.80
22:15:44
23.80

23.80
22:15:44
23.80

23.80
22:15:44
23.80

23.80
22:15:44
23.80

23.80
22:15:44
746.96

23.80
22:15:44
746.96

23.80
22:15:44
746.96

18.08.2019
22:15:44
746.96

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:46

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:46

18.08.2019
23.80
22:15:46

22:15:46
23.80
22:15:46

22:15:46
23.80
22:15:46

22:15:46
23.80
22:15:46

22:15:46
23.80
22:15:46

22:15:47
23.80
22:15:46

22:15:47

23.80

22:15:47

23.80

22:15:47

23.80

23.80

23.80

23.80
22:15:48
23.80

23.80
22:15:48
23.80
```

*Видно, что данные путаются, а одно из значений вовсе не приходит :(*

Comment: Видите ли, проблема в том, что вы изволите принимать данные от UART так, словно бы они кэшируются при приёме в буфер. Буфера нет, вам следует обрабатывать вектор прерывания USART_RX_vect, записывать данные в буфер, а уже в функции loop() обрабатывать их, читая из буфера.

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics, спасибо, попробую!